# Apache Ignite: How to get all items from named cached

Tags: java, ignite

I am trying to get all items from my named PARTITIONED cached. Currenly I am using

```
  List<Cache.Entry<String, Object>> found =
        stmCache.query(new ScanQuery<String, Object>(
        new IgniteBiPredicate<String, Object>() {
           @Override
           public boolean apply(String key, Object person) {
              return true;
           }
        })).getAll();
```

This does not perform very well. It is possible to use:

```
    IgniteCompute compute = ignite.compute();
```

To do the same, or any other suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Try `cache.iterator()` API:

`Iterator<Cache.Entry<String, Object>> iter = cache.iterator();`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15247780)

Comment: @Lundin are you kidding me? This is the correct answer. There is nothing to add, just use this API. Are you familiar with Apache Ignite?

Comment: A single line answer "have you tried ...?" ending with a question mark is a comment, not an answer. Therefore your post ended up in the low-quality review queue. The comment above was auto-posted from that review.  Anyway, you have fixed the answer now, so it is fine.

Comment: @PavelTupitsyn how does this perform? Does it make a network call for each key pair?

Comment: hey @PavelTupitsyn : is there a way to getAll in an async manner?

Answer (score 0):

You can broadcast a task that would run local ScanQueries on each node in multiple threads.

Smth like:

```
ignite.compute(ignite.cluster().forDataNodes("myCache")).broadcast(
  -> {
     UUID locNode = ignite0.cluster().localNodeId();

     int[] parts = ignite0.affinity("myCache").primaryPartitions(locNode);

    Arrays.asList(parts).parallelStream().forEach(p -> {
       new ScanQuery().setLocal(true).setPartition(p).setFilter(...).getAll();
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StreamSupport](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/StreamSupport.html) from JDK 1.8 to convert `Iterable` to `Stream`:

```
Stream<javax.cache.Cache.Entry<YourKey, YourValue>> stream =
    StreamSupport.stream(yourIgniteCache.spliterator(), false);
```

Note that the second param determines if the resulting `Stream` should be parallel or sequential. Also, be aware that Java streams are not reusable, and therefore you can collect everything back to map, for example:

```
Map<YourKey, YourValue> reusableMap = 
     stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(Cache.Entry::getKey, Cache.Entry::getValue));
```