# Apache Ignite - get all from cache

Tags: java, ignite

I'm trying to get all items from a Apache Ignite cache.

Currently I can get an individual item using

```
ClientCache<Integer, BinaryObject> cache = igniteClient.cache("myCache").withKeepBinary();

BinaryObject temp = cache.get(1);
```

To get all keys, Ive tried the following:

```
try(QueryCursor<Entry<Integer,BinaryObject>> cursor = cache.query(new ScanQuery<Integer, BinaryObject>(null))) {
    for (Object p : cursor)
        System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```

This returns a list of `org.apache.ignite.internal.client.thin.ClientCacheEntry` which is internal, and I cannot call `getValue`.

How can I get all items for this cache?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apache Ignite: How to get all items from named cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296027/apache-ignite-how-to-get-all-items-from-named-cached)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using **Iterator** you can get all values and key from cache. below are the sample code to retrieve all values from cache.

```
Iterator<Entry<Integer, BinaryObject>> itr = cache.iterator();                
while(itr.hasNext()) {
    BinaryObject object = itr.next().getValue();
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

Comment: Entry object is from which package??

Comment: cache don't have iterator() method

Answer (score 1):

The following may help you to iterate over all the records in the cache.

```
import javax.cache.Cache.Entry;

import org.apache.ignite.Ignite;
import org.apache.ignite.IgniteCache;
import org.apache.ignite.Ignition;
import org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObject;

public class App5BinaryObject {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Ignition.setClientMode(true);

    try (Ignite client = Ignition
            .start("/Users/amritharajherle/git_new/ignite-learning-by-examples/complete/cfg/ignite-config.xml")) {

        IgniteCache<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> cities = client.cache("City").withKeepBinary();
        int count = 0;
        for (Entry<BinaryObject, BinaryObject> entry : cities) {
            count++;
            BinaryObject key = entry.getKey();
            BinaryObject value = entry.getValue();

            System.out.println("CountyCode=" + key.field("COUNTRYCODE") + ", DISTRICT = " + value.field("DISTRICT")
                    + ", POPULATION = " + value.field("POPULATION") + ", NAME = " + value.field("NAME"));
        }
        System.out.println("total cities count = " + count);

    }

  }

}
```

Comment: this requires thick client

Answer (score 0):

Using Ignite Rest API we can fetch certain Number of records[Size]. I strive a lot and finally found API.

**http://<Server_IP>:8080/ignite?cmd=qryscanexe&pageSize=10&cacheName=**

Add Auth Header As per Ignite Cluster User.